# Curl return bool false in live server but work on local server

Tags: php, curl

```
 $data = array('paymentMethod' => 'NICEPAY', 'goodsName' => 'PROJECT FEE');

 $string = http_build_query($data);

 $ch = curl_init("203.99.61.173:3000/api/users/nicepay");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $response = curl_exec($ch);

 var_dump($response);

 curl_close($ch);
```

> I just tried making this exact call from a local serve server  and it works just fine.

Comment: check your live server has `curl` or not?

Comment: see if curl_mod is enabled in your httpd config file....

Comment: Maybe the IP address is unreachable by the server.

Comment: You wouldn't be getting a return value at all if Curl wasn't enabled - this is likely to be a connectivity issue. Could be the IP is blocked, or a firewall is blocking port 3000, or any number of things. If you can, try running `telnet 203.99.61.173 3000` from the command line,

Comment: curl is enabled  i checked